# Missing separator when trying to ndk build

Tags: android, android-ndk

Why is it that i get a 
jni/Android.mk:9: *** missing separator.  Stop.

error whenever i try  to ndk build? My code is as follows

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  \
gnutls-3.0.12/lib/debug.c \
gnutls-3.0.12/lib/gnutls_pcert.c \ 
gnutls-3.0.12/lib/pkcs11_secret.c \
    gnutls-3.0.12/lib/gnutls_kx.c \
```

is it a syntax error or am i separating my .c files wrongly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which is line 9? If it is pkcs11_secret.c, then that is because you have space at the end of line 8 (where gnutls_pcert.c is). Backslash \ must be at the end of line. There should NOT be anything after it - even spaces. That's because it should escape newline, not space.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i don't quite understand what is wrong, could u please rewrite the above in the correct syntax so i know what i did wrong? Backslash \ is at the end of the line in my example isn't it?

Comment: nvm i've got it now, thnx! :)

Answer (score 0):

its caused by the spaces in the path move the file to a directory on your system that has no spaces in the path. in my case, i had

```
C:\Users\KC ochibili\Desktop\fmodapi44444android.tar\fmodapi44444android\api\lib\armeabi\fmodex.so
```

because of the space between "KC" and  "ochibili" i was getting the errors

so i moved my file to

```
 C:\fmodapi44444android.tar\fmodapi44444android\api\lib\armeabi\libfmodex.so
```

problem solved